# How does the flux capacitor work?

Tags: back-to-the-future, flux-capacitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Back to the Future flux capacitor a capacitor in the first place?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20462/is-back-to-the-future-flux-capacitor-a-capacitor-in-the-first-place)

I'm not aware of any official explanation as to how the flux capacitor works, why it requires 1.21 gigawatts of electrical power, or why it looks like the letter "Y" arranged with three flashing incandescent lamps place in a box.

How does the flux capacitor work in the DeLorean time machine?

Comment: @MajorStackings It asks if the flux capacitor is a capacitor in the first place. I ask how it works!

Comment: I prefaced it as a "possible" dup without vtc. You can tell from my track record that I don't know all I'd like to about timey whimey stuff, but the answer is likely to be similar to 20462's.

Comment: @MajorStackings Agreed!

Comment: It fluxes and stuff....

Comment: @BBlake Alright, how?

Comment: The duplicate answers also answer its operation, which is tied to whether it is a capacitor.

Comment: @MarkBeadles OK, maybe it was answered there but not accepted. If we can somehow bump up that other question then.

Comment: @Secko see my answer in the related thread, although it seems like I more of answer your question than it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time and energy are as interchangeable as [position and momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). Normally over a short enough time period you can make arbitrarily large amounts of energy. One sink to the head though and you realise the principle works in reverse. With arbitrarily large amounts of energy one can make time, potentially store it. I don't understand the *details*, I'm not The Doc.

Lacking any explanation in the canon that I know of, this is probably as good as it gets, unfortunately.